# BigDecimal.setScale(..) changes precisions to 0

Tags: java, avro

I'm using `java` `Corretto 11` and trying to serialize `BigDecimal` value into [avro](https://avro.apache.org) format.

The value:

```java
BigDecimal v = BigDecimal.valueOf(16858.7109375)) //scale = 7, precision = 12
```

then round it

```java
v.setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP) //scale = 5, precision = 0
```

It happens because `BigDecimal`'s internals call static factory method

```java
    public static BigDecimal valueOf(long unscaledVal, int scale) {
        if (scale == 0)
            return valueOf(unscaledVal);
        else if (unscaledVal == 0) {
            return zeroValueOf(scale);
        }
        return new BigDecimal(unscaledVal == INFLATED ?
                              INFLATED_BIGINT : null,
                              unscaledVal, scale, 0); //HERE it sets precision = 0
    }
```

Not a big deal.. however avro's validator and converter has different opinion about it :)

```java
//org.apache.avro.Conversions  (lib avro-1.10.0) 

    private static BigDecimal validate(final LogicalTypes.Decimal decimal, BigDecimal value) { //scale = 5, precision = 0
      ... //nothing happens here

      int precision = decimal.getPrecision(); // 9 as defined in avro schema
      int valuePrecision = value.precision(); // this changes internal precision to 10 (total digits count after scaling)
      if (valuePrecision > precision) { //this is true, and so serialization fails
        if (scaleAdjusted) {
          throw new AvroTypeException("Cannot encode decimal with precision " + valuePrecision + " as max precision "
              + precision + ". This is after safely adjusting scale from " + valueScale + " to required " + scale);
        } else {
          throw new AvroTypeException(
              "Cannot encode decimal with precision " + valuePrecision + " as max precision " + precision);
        }
      }
```

I'm not sure how to fix it.. Is this a bug of `BigDecimal`s internal functions or `avro` converter? Can I hack it somehow?

Comment: Which version of jdk11 corretto are you using? 
        `BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf(16858.7109375);
        final BigDecimal b = a.setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        System.out.println("Scale: " + b.scale() + ", precision: " + b.precision());`
Is returning for me `Scale: 5, precision: 10` with `corretto-11.0.12`

Comment: This is exactly the case. `precision()` method changes internal `precision` field from 0 to 10

Comment: Anyway with 10 precision in you number and 9 max precision in avro it should fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf(16858.7109375);         final 
BigDecimal b = a.setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);         
System.out.println("Scale: " + b.scale() + ", precision: " + b.precision());
//Scale: 5, precision: 10
```

It is true, that internally BigDecimal **b** is showing precision zero, but for each public contract, you will see 10.

In your Avro, if you have `"precision": 9` (max precision) Avro validation will throw an exception because it cannot do downsizing in any way.

You can change your Avro to add bigger max precision (but you have to start from consumers first), or you can just ensure that bigger number will not occur there